# How to make table rows drag and drop in mobile view?

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, html-table, angular-ui

I am using this example on jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/SSSUUUSSS/Bsusr/1/..

Basically it's using angularjs-ui

```
<tbody ui:sortable ng:model="list">
        <tr ng:repeat="item in list" class="item" style="cursor: move;">
            <td>{{$index}}</td>
            <td>{{item}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>{{list}}
```

The drag and drop works on desktop view but not on mobile view?

Is there a way to make it work on mobile?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some time drag and drop not work in mobile, try this module:
mn tounch : https://github.com/ilmente/mnTouch
try this its was working for my drag and drop :)

Comment: Hi Sumit. Thanks for your message. Does it work with touchscreen mobile devices? Did you try it on table rows?

Comment: yes its work for me, I created web application and I used drag drop functionality. it was not working in mobile phones. after adding this plugin its working fine. 
and I thought **that was ul li **  for drag drop. no it was not a table. but try it might be its will be work.